# Calling javascript file residing in a different folder

Tags: javascript

Am new to javascript. Am trying to call an external javascript file from jsp.

I have no problem in doing the above but when I tried to place this **javascript in a different folder and then call**, am not able to do it.

Code which calls js from jsp

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate(this.form)"></input>
```

Added these lines in the *head* part of the jsp

```
<script src="scripts/validate.js">
</script>
```

**Structure:** 
ServletsApp is the main project folder in which WebContent is present. WebContent has folders views and scripts. My jsp resides in views and .js in scripts folder.

**Update:**
LoginExample.jsp

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Share Market Application</title>
<script src="../WebContent/scripts/validate.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="loginForm">
    <h2>Enter user credentials</h2>
    <br> 
    <font size="3" style="TimesNewRoman">Username:</font> 
    <input type="text" name="userId"></input> 
    <br>
    <font size="3" style="TimesNewRoman">Password:</font> 
    <input type="password" name="password"></input> 
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate(this.form)"></input>
    <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel"></input>
</form>
```

**Validate.js**

```
function validate(form)
{
alert("Entered");
alert(document.getElementById("userId"));
var userName=form.userId.value;
alert(userName);
var pwd=form.password.value;
alert(document.getElementById("userId").valueOf());
if(userName=="" || userName!="admin")
    {
    alert("User name is incorrect");
    }
else
    {
    if(pwd=="" || pwd!="admin")
    {
    alert("Password is incorrect");
    }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the console (built-in browser tool) to check for any errors.

Comment: Uhm, since your last response was so informative, I'll suggest installing Firebug. If you have any difficulties with it, download Chrome, it has a built-in console.

Answer (score 3):

check proper path of file

```
<script src="~/Scripts/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

try this

```
<script src="~/WebContent/Scripts/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="../Scripts/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: An alert which I inserted, got executed the first time but from next time onwards, it aint calling again.

Comment: @AnujBalan debug using firebug

Comment: (/MyApp/views/~/Scripts/validate.js) is not available.   Its looking for scripts folder inside views folder I think. But `scripts` and `views` are subfolders of a parent folder

Comment: try this <script src="../Scripts/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Tried it but now its searching for 'scripts' folder outside the parent folder